# Apache cxf jaxrs server ServiceConstructionException

Tags: java, spring, apache, jax-rs, cxf

Hi i have write jaxrs apache cxf rest server .previously it works fine.suddenly it didn't start and it gives this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ServerProviderFactory.createWadlGenerator(ServerProviderFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ServerProviderFactory.<init>(ServerProviderFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ServerProviderFactory.initBaseFactory(ServerProviderFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ServerProviderFactory.createInstance(ServerProviderFactory.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.setupFactory(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:182)
```

And this is the my spring configuration

```
<jaxrs:server name="server" address="${url}">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="serverApi"/>
        <ref bean="swaggerResourceJSON"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jacksonProvider"/>
        <ref bean="resourceWriter"/>
        <ref bean="apiWriter"/>
        <ref bean="corsFilter"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Is there anyone what is the issue ??

Comment: I do not have an answer yet but I am experiencing the same problem right now. If I find an answer I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I was running into this problem while trying to test a CXF JAX_RX API. I was running into this problem while trying to create a server in a test situation. I tried a few different approaches...

This game me the ClassCastException:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setTransportId(LocalTransportFactory.TRANSPORT_ID);
sf.setAddress("api/address");
sf.setResourceClasses(OurJaxResource.class);
server = sf.create();
```

As did this:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setResourceClasses(OurJaxResource.class);

List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
sf.setProviders(providers);
sf.setResourceProvider(OurJaxResource.class, new SingletonResourceProvider(new OurJaxResource(), true));
sf.setAddress(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);

server = sf.create();
```

What ended up working for me to get around that exception was this:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setBindingId(JAXRSBindingFactory.JAXRS_BINDING_ID);
sf.setAddress("api/address");
server = serverFactory.create();
server.start();
```

Not sure of your specific situation but hopefully this at least gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a cxf dependencies mismatch.cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs 3.2.2 was not compatible with cxf-bundle-jaxrs 2.7.18 which I needed for jsonProvider-rs. I was able to solve the problem by replacing cxf-bundle-jaxrs it with cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers 3.2.2