# WadlGenerator cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter after upgrading to cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.13

Tags: java, spring, maven, cxf, javax

Getting the following issue while upgrading to cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs v3.1.13.
I am using javax.ws.rs v2.0.1, Spring v4.3.10.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxxx': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988) [catalina.jar:8.5.23-dev]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860) [catalina.jar:8.5.23-dev]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: null
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:219) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ServerProviderFactory.createWadlGenerator(ServerProviderFactory.java:108) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ServerProviderFactory.(ServerProviderFactory.java:100) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ServerProviderFactory.createInstance(ServerProviderFactory.java:120) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.setupFactory(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:234) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:182) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.13.jar:3.1.13]
    ... 32 common frames omitted

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171271/apache-cxf-jaxrs-server-serviceconstructionexception) answer?

Comment: I did! It is different in my case, I see it when I try to start the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used maven tree and identified that there was another jar was loading a different version, and that was happening in a random behavior because it depends on what the class loader loads first. Anyways the fix was just excluding that version from the dependency.